# Can't change size of images in react-bootstrap carousel

Tags: react-bootstrap

I can't seem to increase the size of the images in my carousel.  I'd like the images to be larger.  No matter what the size of the source image, they all appear the same size when I run the carousel.  I suspect I need to increase the size of the viewport, but can't figure out how to do that.

```
function Work() {

  return (
    <Carousel fade indicators={false} controls={false} pause={false}>
      <Carousel.Item interval={5000}>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={newsBlur}
          alt="News Flash blurred"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption style={styles.carouselCaption}>
          <h3>
            News Flash gathers news based on the user's
            news category preferences.
          </h3>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my images were actually displaying full screen, which is the default setting for the react-bootstrap carousel.  My images were over a transparent background making them appear to only cover part of the screen.  When I resized the image, the component just stretched it to fill the full screen, so it didn't appear to do anything.  I needed to re-create my images with a different ratio of transparent back ground and viewable image.